# Unhide and hide some element within the form using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi everyone I am trying to hide and unhide some elements inside the form eg when a text area is clicked the post button must be enable.The problem is that i am not good with javascript so I need help/direction on this, even if is the link for the tutorials it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complete example with both HTML, JavaScript, and jQuery. You basically have a textarea and a hidden (and disabled) button. The JavaScript code simply adds a click event to the textarea and enables the button inside the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                $('textarea#some-textarea-id').click(function(){
                    $('button#some-button-id').show().removeAttr('disabled');
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea id="some-text-area-id"></textarea>
            <button id="some-button-id" style="display: none" disabled>CLICK ME</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Resources:**

> http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/
>   http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/
>   https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: this is what i need i read those they actually make sense ,so what if the buttons are more than one and they do the different job eg POST and CANCEL button.

Comment: I've updated the code provided with IDs and how to select elements via their IDs :)

Comment: I ma trying to use this method but replacing the form with the div since the form is making the page to refresh which i don't want to.I've tried to google this but most of them depends on the form not the div.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague, but the following code will probably help you figure it out:

```
$('#your_textarea_id').on('click', function(){ // add an event listener to your tag/textarea
    $('#post_button_id').removeAttr('disabled'); // removes the disable of your post button
})
```

If you want to hide/show, then just replace removeAttr('disabled') with toggle(), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
Refer to the code below    

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').on('click', function(){
                        $('#button-id').attr('disabled', false);
                    });
    });

where '#button-id' is the id of button you want to disable on the click event of textarea.
```